# Cron job with aws eb and laravel task scheduling

Tags: amazon-web-services, cron, scheduled-tasks, laravel-5.3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I would like to know how create a cron with AWS elastic beanstalk and laravel task scheduling.

Currently AWS elastic beanstalk propose to create a `cron.yaml` file but this file take in paramters only the url. However laravel need to execute a command. I don't know how to do it.

Can you help me please ?

Answer (score 0):

Having done lots of googling, I don't think AWS EB supports executing the schedule:run command directly from app. Instead, the command will have to be triggered from an endpoint just as explained in the docs [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features-managing-env-tiers.html).

I found a package [here](https://github.com/dusterio/laravel-aws-worker) which helped me setup the endpoint easily

Hope it helps...

Comment: Hi, thanks for your good response, can you explain me how create a worker environment. This environment sould be same to my web environment or it's a different application ?

Answer (score 0):

Getting Laravel Scheduled tasks working is a lot simpler if you just do this:

`sudo vi /etc/crontab`

and add the line to the bottom of the file:

`* * * * * webapp cd /var/www/html/<yourAppFolder>/ && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1`

Done!